# Strange continue keyword usage

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, continue

I'm reviewing some Java code, and have run into this kind of thing a second time now.

```
while (true)
  try
  {
    //some simple statements
    continue;
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      SamsetUtils.LogError(this.logger, e.getMessage() + ".29");
    }
    if (!SamsetUtils.BlockingDistributorThread)
    {
      //some very long and critical code here
    }
  }
  //several catch blocks follow
```

To my understanding, the critical code would always be omitted, since the continue statement would always be executed and would always start another iteration immediately. First I marked a similar situation as a bug, but this time it raised my suspicions, because it's all part of supposedly working code that's being used commercially. Does this snippet work somehow, in a way I'm not aware of?

Similar situation here:

```
 while (true)
  try {
    //some simple statements

    if (notifications != null) {
      int i = 0; continue;

      this.recivedNotifies.add(notifications[i].getName());

      i++; if (i >= notifications.length)
      {
        makeCallBack();
      }
    } else {
      Thread.sleep(2000L);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    //catch statements
  }
```

Comment: That snippet shouldn't even compile, let alone work correctly -- the Java compiler should give an error about "unreachable statement".  Are you sure that that's the **exact** code you're seeing?

Comment: Yes. It is Unreachable code.

Comment: Yeah, I copied&pasted straight from the file, and just edited out some statements in marked places for clarity. Can't try to compile it right now due to missing library issues, but the code was actually decompiled from a jar

Comment: Sounds like the decompiler got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those snippets come from decompiled code, and it was indeed the decompiler getting confused. I checked it with another one and it produced different, although also crazy, results. Thanks for all the help.